# Angular modules import with webpack - Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I've been trying to setup angular 1 with webpack and ran into an issue with import modules, let's say I want to import ramda from node_modules

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uirouter form 'angular-ui-router';
import routing from './app.config';
import * as ramda from 'ramda';


angular.module('app', [uirouter, ramda])
  .config(routing);
```

I get an error:  Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object. If I console ramda, it is indeed an object and I understand I need a string, but I just couldn't figure out how to get it?

Answer (score 1):

Change it to `import ramda from"ramda"`.
This is because the export of the module is the module name.
When you write `import * as ramda` you import the namespace object, which is an object containing all the exports of that module.

If you are using TypeScript, you may need to add a `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to your tsconfig.json. 
[allowSyntheticDefaultImports](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7518)